# How to split comma-separated values into multiple rows in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, normalization

```
SELECT year, movietitle, director, actorname 
  FROM films11 
  WHERE actorname like '%Christina Ricci%' 
  order by year asc;
```

produces the following in ORACLE SQL Developer from the original data schema.

[image: screenshot]

I want to transform the whole table so that the primary key becomes the `actor name`. (like in the second table)

This way the query

```
SELECT year, movietitle, director, actorname 
  FROM films11 
  WHERE actorname like '%Christina Ricci%' 
  order by year asc;
```

will produce only the searched item (either create a new view, or change the data schema completely.) (third table)

Comment: Turn the monitor sideways

Comment: You already have the answer in the screenshot.  Your new table just needs to have a row for every distinct Actor in the `ACTORNAME` column as shown in the third table of your screenshot.  Or alternatively, you can use the suggestion by @Strawberry.

Comment: Table has too many rows to be able to do that. I am wondering if there is a SQL query to split the names in  the `ACTORNAME` column by the comma, like you said into a new row ...

Comment: There is a way but SQL being a special-purpose language best used for set-based retrieval/manipulation operations, nuances like this is complex and may involve procedural SQL. I advised import into a general-purpose language, Java/Python/PHP/R and wrangle from there (i.e., split by comma, reshape to rows).

Comment: Have you considered normalizing the database design?  You could have an `actor` table, a `film` table, and an `actedInFilm` table.  Querying this would be more straightforward.

Comment: Side note: you don't want the primary key to be name: **NAMES ARE NOT UNIQUE**.  (Although this is apparently not necessarily true for actors within a specific guild, multiple guilds may end up with actors with the same name, and I'm not sure if they allow "reuse" of names later....)

Comment: I've made you the full script for an automatic normalization of your DB on 4 tables, just take a look. (careful, it's oracle 12c syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Step 1 : *"How to blow up a database"*

From :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ad3/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
select * from films11
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ad3/5/0)**:

```
| YEAR | DIRECTOR | MOVIETITLE |      ACTORNAME |
|------|----------|------------|----------------|
| 2000 |     dir1 |     title1 |      act1,act2 |
| 2001 |     dir2 |     title2 | act1,act2,act3 |
| 2002 |     dir1 |     title3 |           act4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select YT.year, YT.movietitle,
       REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YT.actorname||',','.*?,',1,lvl.lvl),',','') AS actorname
from films11 YT
join (select level as lvl 
      from dual 
      connect by level <= (select max(regexp_count(actorname,',')+1) from films11)
     ) lvl on lvl.lvl <= regexp_count(YT.actorname,',')+1
     order by YT.year, YT.movietitle, actorname
```

With a nice **Cartesian product** :

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ad3/5/1)**:

```
| YEAR | MOVIETITLE | ACTORNAME |
|------|------------|-----------|
| 2000 |     title1 |      act1 |
| 2000 |     title1 |      act2 |
| 2001 |     title2 |      act1 |
| 2001 |     title2 |      act2 |
| 2001 |     title2 |      act3 |
| 2002 |     title3 |      act4 |
```

You run it **ONCE** and use it to move everything to a normalized DB

---

Here is the full script to change your schema to something more convenient...

```
CREATE TABLE actors(
    id_actor NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    act_name VARCHAR2(100)
) 
;

CREATE TABLE directors(
    id_director NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    dir_name VARCHAR2(100)
) 
;

CREATE TABLE movies(
    id_movie NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    mov_year NUMBER,
    mov_name VARCHAR2(100),
    director_id NUMBER
) 
;

CREATE TABLE playedby(
    movie_id NUMBER,
    actor_id NUMBER
) 
;

    INSERT INTO directors (dir_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT director dir_name
    FROM films11
    ;

    INSERT INTO movies (mov_year, mov_name, director_id)
    SELECT year mov_year, movietitle mov_name, directors.id_director director_id
    FROM films11
    INNER JOIN directors ON directors.dir_name = films11.director

    ;

    INSERT INTO actors (act_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT t.actorname act_name
    FROM (
        SELECT YT.year, YT.movietitle,
               REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YT.actorname||',','.*?,',1,lvl.lvl),',','') AS actorname
        FROM films11 YT
        JOIN (SELECT level AS lvl 
              FROM dual 
              CONNECT BY level <= (SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(actorname,',')+1) FROM films11)
             ) lvl ON lvl.lvl <= REGEXP_COUNT(YT.actorname,',')+1
    ) t
    ;

    INSERT INTO playedby (movie_id, actor_id)
    SELECT movies.id_movie movie_id, actors.id_actor actor_id
    FROM (
        SELECT YT.year, YT.movietitle,
               REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YT.actorname||',','.*?,',1,lvl.lvl),',','') AS actorname
        FROM films11 YT
        JOIN (SELECT level AS lvl 
              FROM dual 
              CONNECT BY level <= (SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(actorname,',')+1) FROM films11)
             ) lvl ON lvl.lvl <= REGEXP_COUNT(YT.actorname,',')+1
    ) t
    INNER JOIN actors ON t.actorname = actors.act_name
    INNER JOIN movies ON t.year = movies.mov_year AND t.movietitle = movies.mov_name 

    ;
```

After that you can just make a select like that :

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT mov_year, mov_name, dir_name, act_name 
FROM movies
INNER JOIN directors ON directors.id_director = movies.director_id
INNER JOIN playedby ON movies.id_movie = playedby.movie_id
INNER JOIN actors ON playedby.actor_id = actors.id_actor
WHERE act_name like '%act2%' 
order by mov_year asc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ad3/5/2)**:

```
| MOV_YEAR | MOV_NAME | DIR_NAME | ACT_NAME |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|     2000 |   title1 |     dir1 |     act2 |
|     2001 |   title2 |     dir2 |     act2 |
```

Comment: **Beautiful** After your response which is super helpful. [SQLFiddle] website (http://sqlfiddle.com) is like the second best thing i learned today.